# Bash RegEx to check floating point numbers from user input

Tags: regex, bash, expression, bash4

I'm relatively new to bash programming and i am currently creating a simple calculator.

It needs to use floating point numbers and check they are so.

I have a checkNumbers function:

```
function checkNumber {

    regExp=[0-9]

    if [ $testNo =~ $regExp ]
    then
        echo "That is a number!"
        let check=1
    else
        echo "Damn! Not A Number!"
    fi
}
```

where i get the user to input a number like this:

```
while [ $check -eq 0]
do
    echo "Please enter a number
    read testNo
    echo ""
    checkNumber
done
```

This does not work, i get this error:

> ./calculator.sh: line 39: [: =~: binary operator expected

line 39 is:

```
if [ $testNo =~ $regExp ]
```

I have tried lots of Regular Expressions like:

```
^*[0-9]*$
```

and

```
^*[0-9]\.[0.9]*$
```

etc etc.

also, i have tied other ways of performing the check:

```
case $testNo
in
    ^*[0-9]*$) echo "That is a number!";;
    *) echo "Error! Not a number!";;
esac
```

and

```
if [ $testNo = ^*[0-9]*$ ]
then
    echo "etc etc"
else
    echo "oops"
fi
```

I also need this to work with floating point numbers.

could someone please let me know how i go about this?

Comment: I hope you don't need numbers of the form `12345e42`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This regex `^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$` will match only digits with an optional `.`:

```
$ echo 30 | grep -Eq '^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' && echo Match
Match

$ echo 30.10 | grep -Eq '^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' && echo Match
Match

$ echo 30. | grep -Eq '^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' && echo Match
Match

$ echo +30 | grep -Eq '^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' && echo Match
Match

$ echo -30 | grep -Eq '^[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' && echo Match
Match
```

I think when you tried `^*[0-9]` you wanted `^[0-9]*`

Rexeplanation:

```
^       # Match start of string
[-+]?   # Match a leading + or - (optional)
[0-9]+  # Match one or more digit
\.?     # Match a literal . (optional, escaped)
[0-9]*  # Match zero or more digits
$       # Match the end of the string
```

Note: this matches numbers followed by a `.` like `30.`, not sure if this is acceptable for you.

Edit: Don't quote the `regex`

```
testNo=30.00

if [[ $testNo =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; then 
    echo Match
fi

>>> Match
```

Comment: This will not match negative numbers. `:-(`

Comment: Forgot about those things :|

Comment: Good. Now I hope the OP doesn't need `1.2345e42`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have put this: ` if [[ $testNo =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$' ]] ` but it doesn't seem to like floats, it says they're not a number, is what i have done correct? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

To use that type of feature, you need the  `[[ ... ]]` version of the conditional. `[` is the "old" `test` command and doesn't handle regular expressions at all.

```
#! /bin/bash
function checkNumber {
    regExp='^[+-]?([0-9]+\.?|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$'
    if [[ $testNo =~ $regExp ]]
    then
        echo "That is a number!"
        let check=1
    else
        echo "Damn! Not A Number!"
    fi
}
testNo=1
checkNumber
testNo=-1.2
checkNumber
testNo=+.2
checkNumber
testNo=+0.
checkNumber
testNo=a
checkNumber
testNo=hello2you
checkNumber

$ ./t.sh
That is a number!
That is a number!
That is a number!
That is a number!
Damn! Not A Number!
Damn! Not A Number!
```

See [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

An explanation on the regex:

```
^ Anchor at start of string
$ Anchor at end of string
```

These two make the regex match the whole string passed, partial matches are not allowed.

```
[+-]
```

matches either `+` or `-`.

```
[+-]?
```

makes that part optional, so the above matches exactly `+`, `-` or nothing at all.

Then there's an alternation `(part1|part2)` which will match if `part1` or `part2` matches.

Part one is:

```
[0-9]+\.?
```

which matches one or more (`+`) digits (but not zero digits/empty set) and an optional `.`. This handles numbers of the form `123` and `534.`. But not just `.`.

Part two is:

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]+
```

This matches zero or more (`*`) digits, followed by a `.`, followed by one or more digits. This matches all other floats like `1.3` or `.543` (without exponent notation), but still excludes just `.`.

Comment: `testNo=hello2you` ---> `That is a number!` `:-(`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for keeping watch :) Should handle reasonable floats now.

Comment: Except negative floats, and except floats of the form `42.` and `.42`

Comment: Tough crowd! I'm not sure I like `42.` being accepted (that makes the regex a bit hairy if you still want to exclude `.` - might be better options), but `.42` is perfectly reasonable. Edited anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to validate 

while [ true ]; do
clear
echo "Introduce the numeric value: "
read -r var
if [[ $var =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+)$ ]]
   then
      echo "You introduced an integer value (without decimals)"
      read
   else
      if [[ $var =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+\.)$ ]]
         then
            echo "Incomplete floating value (no values provided at the right of the point)"
            read
         else
            if [[ $var =~ ^[+-]?(\.[0-9]+)$ ]]
               then
                  echo "Incomplete floating value (no values provided at the left of the point)"
                  read
               else
                  if [[ $var =~ ^[+-]?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$ ]]
                     then
                        echo "You introduced a correct floating value"
                        read
                     else
                        echo "You introduced something other than a valid numeric value"
                        read
                  fi
            fi
      fi
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I include an optional dot at the start.

```
       user@debian:~$ testNo=.01
       user@debian:~$ if [[ $testNo =~ ^[+-]?[.]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; 
                    > then         
                    > echo Match; 
                    > fi
         Match
```